# From dataframe with values per min max to value per key

Tags: r, max, lookup, min

I have a dataframe with values defined per bucket. (See df1 below)
Now I have another dataframe with values within those buckets for which I want to look up a value from the bucketed dataframe (See df2 below)

Now I would like to have the result df3 below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(MIN = c(1,4,8), MAX = c(3, 6, 10), VALUE = c(3, 56, 8))
df2 <- data.frame(KEY = c(2,5,9))
df3 <- data.frame(KEY = c(2,5,9), VALUE = c(3, 56, 8))

> df1
  MIN MAX VALUE
1   1   3     3
2   4   6    56
3   8  10     8
> df2
  KEY
1   2
2   5
3   9
> df3
  KEY VALUE
1   2     3
2   5    56
3   9     8
```

**EDIT :** 
Extended the example.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(MIN = c(1,4,8, 14), MAX = c(3, 6, 10, 18), VALUE = c(3, 56, 3, 5))
> df2 <- data.frame(KEY = c(2,5,9,18,3))
> df3 <- data.frame(KEY = c(2,5,9,18,3), VALUE = c(3, 56, 3, 5, 3))
> df1
  MIN MAX VALUE
1   1   3     3
2   4   6    56
3   8  10     3
4  14  18     5
> df2
  KEY
1   2
2   5
3   9
4  18
5   3
> df3
  KEY VALUE
1   2     3
2   5    56
3   9     3
4  18     5
5   3     3
```

Comment: Is this a representative example of your real dataset, or just a simple case? Here it looks like each `KEY` in `df2` belongs in only one of the `MIN, MAX` ranges in `df1` and, also, it is `+1, -1` from `MIN, MAX` respectively.

Comment: This is a really simplified version. It should accomodate multiple values in each bucket and the value can be any value within, or on the boundaries of each bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that `KEY`, `MIN` and `MAX` are integers, so we can create a sequence of keys and then join.

```
df1 <- data.frame(MIN = c(1,4,8, 14), MAX = c(3, 6, 10, 18), VALUE = c(3, 56, 3, 5))
df2 <- data.frame(KEY = c(2,5,9,18,3))

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(VALUE, id=row_number()) %>%             # for each value and row id
  nest() %>%                                       # nest rest of columns
  mutate(KEY = map(data, ~seq(.$MIN, .$MAX))) %>%  # create a sequence of keys
  unnest(KEY) %>%                                  # unnest those keys
  right_join(df2, by="KEY") %>%                    # join the other dataset
  select(KEY, VALUE) 

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#     KEY VALUE
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2.00  3.00
# 2  5.00 56.0 
# 3  9.00  3.00
# 4 18.0   5.00
# 5  3.00  3.00
```

Or, group just by the row number and add `VALUE` in the `map`:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id=row_number()) %>% 
  nest() %>%                 
  mutate(K = map(data, ~data.frame(VALUE = .$VALUE, 
                                   KEY = seq(.$MIN, .$MAX)))) %>%
  unnest(K) %>%
  right_join(df2, by="KEY") %>% 
  select(KEY, VALUE)
```

Comment: Cool! Although it doesn't work when the VALUE of the first bucket equals the value of a latter bucket.

Comment: Can you post an example in your question? If I can replicate the problem I'll be able to fix it.

Comment: I got your point. I group by `VALUE` so having the same `VALUE` in another row will break the process. So, I'll add the row id/number in the grouping in order to have unique combinations.

Answer (score 0):

A very good and well-thought-out solution from @AntioniosK.

Here's a base R solution implemented as a general lookup function given as arguments a key dataframe and a bucket dataframe defined as listed in the question. The lookup values need not be unique or contiguous in this example, taking account of @Michael's comment that values may occur in more than one row (though normally such lookups would use unique ranges).

```
lookup = function(keydf, bucketdf){
  keydf$rowid = 1:nrow(keydf)
  T = merge(bucketdf, keydf)
  T = T[T$KEY >= T$MIN & T$KEY <= T$MAX,]
  T = merge(T, keydf, all.y = TRUE)
  T[order(T$rowid), c("rowid", "KEY", "VALUE")]
}
```

The first merge uses a Cartesian join of all rows in the key to all rows in the bucket list. Such joins can be inefficient if the number of rows in the real tables is large, as the result of joining x rows in the key to y rows in the bucket would be xy rows; I doubt this would be a problem in this case unless x or y run into thousands of rows.

The second merge is done to recover any key values which are *not* matched to rows in the bucket list.

Using the example data as listed in @AntioniosK's post:

```
> lookup(df2, df1)
  rowid KEY VALUE
2     1   2     3
4     2   5    56
5     3   9     3
1     4  18     5
3     5   3     3
```

Using key and bucket exemplars that test edge cases (where the key = the min or the max), where a key value is not in the bucket list (the value 50 in df2A), and where there is a non-unique range (row 6 of df4 below):

```
df4 <- data.frame(MIN = c(1,4,8, 20, 30, 22), MAX = c(3, 6, 10, 25, 40, 24), VALUE = c(3, 56, 8, 10, 12, 23))
df2A <- data.frame(KEY = c(3, 6, 22, 30, 50))

df4
  MIN MAX VALUE
1   1   3     3
2   4   6    56
3   8  10     8
4  20  25    10
5  30  40    12
6  22  24    23

> df2A
  KEY
1   3
2   6
3  22
4  30
5  50

> lookup(df2A, df4)
  rowid KEY VALUE
1     1   3     3
2     2   6    56
3     3  22    10
4     3  22    23
5     4  30    12
6     5  50    NA
```

As shown above, the lookup in this case returns two values for the non-unique ranges matching the key value 22, and NA for values in the key but not in the bucket list.